# Class hierarchy when writing 3D graphics software

Tags: oop, inheritance, 3d, methodology, code-organization

This is sort of a methodology question.

When writing software that makes use of object-oriented libraries to abstract OpenGL and the like, should you (or would you) choose to extend the OpenGL helper objects and add your own business logic onto them, or create your basic business objects and then have the OpenGL helpers as a property of them.

For example

Let's say I have an OpenGL library that provides a class

OpenGLBillboard

which draws a 2D sprite that faces the camera

if I have some sort of business object that is going to be rendered using that class, is it wise to simply extend OpenGLBillboard and build on top of it, or should I just have an OpenGLBillboard object that is a property on what is essentially a base class in my software?

It seems like inheritance in this case could be dangerous because if the base class ever has to change due to requirements, the refactoring could be painful ... whereas if I just go the property route, I have a little more upfront boilerplate to write.

Your thoughts?

Thanks

P.S. forgive me for saying "business object". I just didn't want to say "model" a whole lot in a topic about 3D and have people be confused as to my meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would probably have my business object contain (privately) a "Billboard" instance, and not tie it directly to OpenGL at all.

The business object would just be asked to render, and redirect it's methods through the Billboard instance.  This would allow you to swap out a different implementation (if you decide to go with something other than a Billboard) or a different backend (ie: a Direct3D rendering pipeline) without changing the business object at all.